# How to use MediaPlayer in Android

Tags: android

In my application I want use **MediaPlayer** in **Recyclerview** and I have **2 viewType** of `viewholder` adapter. 
I write below codes, but after run application and click on play button show me force close error! 
**ViewHolder codes:**

```
class WhiteViewHolder internal constructor(
    whiteBinding: ItemChatWhiteBinding, private val context: Context, private val mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(whiteBinding.root), SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private val binding: ItemChatWhiteBinding = whiteBinding

    private var myHolder: WhiteViewHolder? = null
    private val seekBarUpdater by lazy { SeekBarUpdater() }
    private var currentPlayingPosition = -1

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun bindData(item: ResponseChatList.Data.Result) {
        binding.apply {
            //Media
            myHolder = this@WhiteViewHolder
            if (bindingAdapterPosition == currentPlayingPosition) {
                updatePlayingView()
            } else {
                updateNonPlayingView()
            }
            //Files
            if (item.chatFile != null) {
                fileVisibilityMode(item.chatFile.type!!)
                whiteFileLay.isVisible = true
                when (item.chatFile.type) {
                    VOICE -> {
                        whiteVoiceBtn.setOnClickListener {
                            if (bindingAdapterPosition == currentPlayingPosition) {
                                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                                    if (mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying) {
                                        mediaPlayer!!.pause()
                                    } else {
                                        mediaPlayer!!.start()
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                currentPlayingPosition = bindingAdapterPosition
                                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                                    if (myHolder != null) {
                                        updateNonPlayingView()
                                    }
                                    mediaPlayer!!.release()
                                }
                                myHolder = this@WhiteViewHolder
                                playSound(fileUrl(item.chatFile.id!!))
                            }
                            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                                updatePlayingView()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                whiteFileLay.isVisible = false
            }
        }
    }

    private fun fileUrl(id: Int): String {
        return "${BASE_URL}core/shared/files/$id/downloads?token=${userToken.replace("Bearer ", "")}"
    }

    //Voice
    private fun playSound(url: String) {
        //mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url)
        mediaPlayer.prepare()
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener { releaseMediaPlayer() }
        mediaPlayer.start()
    }

    private fun releaseMediaPlayer() {
        if (myHolder != null) {
            updateNonPlayingView()
        }
        mediaPlayer?.release()
        //mediaPlayer = null
        currentPlayingPosition = -1
    }

    override fun onProgressChanged(p0: SeekBar?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean) {
        if (p2)
            mediaPlayer?.seekTo(p1)
    }

    override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {}

    override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {}

    inner class SeekBarUpdater : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            if (myHolder != null && mediaPlayer != null) {
                binding.whiteVoiceProgress.progress = mediaPlayer!!.currentPosition
                binding.whiteVoiceProgress.postDelayed(this, 100)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun updateNonPlayingView() {
        binding.whiteVoiceProgress.removeCallbacks(seekBarUpdater)
        binding.whiteVoiceProgress.isEnabled = false
        binding.whiteVoiceProgress.progress = 0
        binding.whiteVoiceBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play)
    }

    private fun updatePlayingView() {
        binding.whiteVoiceProgress.max = mediaPlayer!!.duration
        binding.whiteVoiceProgress.progress = mediaPlayer!!.currentPosition
        binding.whiteVoiceProgress.isEnabled = true
        if (mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying) {
            binding.whiteVoiceProgress.postDelayed(seekBarUpdater, 100)
            binding.whiteVoiceBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause)
        } else {
            binding.whiteVoiceBtn.removeCallbacks(seekBarUpdater)
            binding.whiteVoiceBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play)
        }
    }
}
```

**Error logs:**

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException
>     at android.media.MediaPlayer.nativeSetDataSource(Native Method)
>     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1260)
>     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1247)
>     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1212)
>     at com.myapp.holders.WhiteViewHolder.playSound(WhiteViewHolder.kt:173)
>     at com.myapp.holders.WhiteViewHolder.bindData$lambda-3$lambda-2(WhiteViewHolder.kt:127)
>     at com.myapp.holders.WhiteViewHolder.$r8$lambda$8dQ74w1DCqyApwY7CuInHCptTG8(Unknown
> ```
>
> Source:0)
> at com.myapp.holders.WhiteViewHolder$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onClick(Unknown
> Source:4)

Show me error for this line: `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url)`

**Adapter codes:**

```
class ChatAdapterNew constructor(
    private val context: Context, val items: MutableList<Result>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    //Types
    private val viewTypeBlue = 1
    private val viewTypeWhite = 2
    private lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer

    init {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return if (viewType == viewTypeBlue) {
            BlueViewHolder(
                ItemChatBlueBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false),
                context, mediaPlayer
            )
        } else {
            WhiteViewHolder(
                ItemChatWhiteBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false),
                context,mediaPlayer
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == viewTypeBlue) {
            (holder as BlueViewHolder).bindData(items[position])
        } else {
            (holder as WhiteViewHolder).bindData(items[position])
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (items[position].toUserId?.id == PHYSICIAN_DATA?.id) {
            viewTypeBlue
        } else {
            viewTypeWhite
        }
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int) = position.toLong()
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: seems that the source (file, http-adress) is not available for the device...

Comment: @GGKstandsforUkraine I sure url is ok, because when uncomment this line : mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer() . play media